# Why the link for tails done this?

Tags: windows, tails, firefox

I dont speak well english so, in "normal style" is my fuckin english style** and in bold is the GoGol translate :)

**Windows 10 user I have no confidence in this system. So I came here logically.**

When i want to click the tails link...
[image]

The response done this :
[image]

So WHY? It's not "my" firefox, i'm on tails page on other tab (OK, there's more 40 mn the ISO's download "working" for Government *[Oops there's a title of A Tribe Call Red, sorry ;-)]* for nothing)
EDIT: Humm... **Now I can not access any links related to the tails site**

** Nobody's perfect, i'm french...
**If someone wants to make corrections, I promise I would not blame him.**

Comment: It seems somebody is intercepting your Internet traffic and sending you a wrong certificate. The correct fingerprint for https://tails.boum.org is `F8:DC:67:21:96:77:46:F5:9D:77:BD:7B:87:C1:39:42:C8:4E:4B:25:97:34:AC:E2:80:24:99:35:D9:81:9C:B6`.

Comment: I think so too. But I do not know how to make use of the fingerprint...

Comment: Your solution is to use BitTorrent to download a distribution

Comment: The "Tails Download And Verify" part of it suggests it's related to the Tails firefox addon, is it possible it is out of date and has the wrong pin?

Comment: @JensKubieziel: well... just a marginal correction: this is the correct fingerprint, but not only for *tails.boum.org*, it is a wildcard-certificate for **.boum.org*.

Answer (score 3):

Someone is interfering with TLS, or your browser has an old certificate pin that is no longer valid and your browser requires updating.

Tails provides mirrors, if access to the main website is blocked. You could try accessing [one of the mirrors](https://tails.boum.org/blueprint/HTTP_mirror_pool/) to download the ISO.

> https://tails.mirror.metalgamer.eu/tails/stable/
>
> https://tails.c3l.lu/tails/stable/
>
> https://16.dl.amnesia.boum.org/tails/stable/
>
> https://dl2.crypto-rebels.de/tails/stable/
>
> http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/tails/stable/
>
> https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/tails/stable/
>
> https://mirrors.kernel.org/tails/stable/

Inside of these mirrors there should be a folder called `tails-i386-x.y`, where x and y are the latest version numbers (at current time of writing it is 2.6).

Download both the `.iso` and the `.iso.sig` and verify the signature. Since these mirrors are being served from infrastructure that Tails doesn't own or maintain, it's twice as important to verify the authenticity of the signature.

Alternatively, the following magnet link should work:

`magnet:?xt=urn:btih:ZEAFJLWHSXEYJE6M4QGZCJ22CGZSRWBH`

Note that since you've no reason to trust my magnet link, you should also download the .iso.sig from one of the mirrors above and again verify the signature of the ISO.

For anyone wanting to verify, the magnet link was generated through the following code:

```
import bencode,hashlib,base64
f = open('tails-i386-2.6.torrent').read()
df = bencode.bdecode(f)
h = hashlib.sha1(bencode.bencode(df['info'])).digest()
print "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:%s" % (base64.b32encode(h))
```